# Calendário em um app Android

Tags: android, google-calendar

estou tentando desenvolver no meu app android, uma funcionalidade de onde eu possa consultar, cadastrar, etc eventos em um calendário. Tentei o CalendarView e cheguei no ponto de clicar em uma data e disparar um evento. Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Teria uma forma mais simples de fazer isso utilizando o GoogleCalendar? Como faço para colocar uma marcação na data onde foi criada o evento para saber que naquele dia tem algo cadastrado? Dei uma lida em Google calendar mas fiquei um pouco confuso. Sou novo em android e preciso de ajuda. Obridado

Comment: Bruno, existe sim uma API do Google Calendar, porém precisa de internet e o acesso é feito por REST ao endpoint do google ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/get_started). A API tem cliente para Java. Outra alternativa é usar o Calendar Provider para acessar e modificar os calendários locais do dispositivo, sem necessidade de internet. Porém está disponível apenas para o SDK 14+, dê uma olhada em: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html. Ainda não cheguei a usar, mas em breve irei precisar e acho que vou seguir pelo Calendar Provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode abrir a janela de calendário da seguinte forma:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

Caso você precise adicionar datas utilize da seguinte forma:

```
//Cria uma intent para abertura de uma nova activity.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

//Configurações do evento.
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Teste de Titulo");
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Local do evento");
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Teste de descrição");

//Configuração de data do evento
GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 28, 08);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
calDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
calDate.getTimeInMillis());

//Marca o evento como dia inteiro.
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

//Define se será repetido
intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=11;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH");

//Marca como privado e como ocupado.
intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
```

Caso você queira utilizar dentro de sua aplicação, você terá que fazer diferente.
Existe essa biblioteca de terceiros que achei bem interessante e é bonita, ela pode te auxiliar.

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Abraço.

Comment: Lembrando que usar a `CalendarContracts` requere a SDK 14+, e o Caldroid não acessa o calendário do Usuário, no próprio repositório ele diz: "Caldroid is simply an UI library and it does not connect to user calendar database or fetch any user's events. If your app wants to display these events on Caldroid".

Comment: Achei um outro Post interessante e muito promissor. Mas não testei para ver se tudo funciona, espero testar em breve e ai posto o resultado... mas se alguem já quiser testar segue o link: [Aqui](http://abinashandroid.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/how-to-create-custom-calendar-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o que você precisa, mas também tive que trabalhar com calendário e achei esse biblioteca muito boa:

https://github.com/shrikanth7698/Collapsible-Calendar-View-Android

```
final CollapsibleCalendar collapsibleCalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    collapsibleCalendar.setCalendarListener(new CollapsibleCalendar.CalendarListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDaySelect() {
            Day day = viewCalendar.getSelectedDay();
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Selected Day: "
                    + day.getYear() + "/" + (day.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + day.getDay());
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataUpdate() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMonthChange() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onWeekChange(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/170864)

Comment: @Isac resposta alterada